# My legal-sized document prints out with the bottom 4 inches cut off

Tags: ios, macos

My legal-sized document prints with the bottom 4 inches cut off.  If I send the document to myself as an attachment by e-mail, it prints fine.  I'm using a brand-new iMac El Capitan and Word 2016. The Apple rep at the store where I bought it says he doesn't know why it does that.

How can I fix this so it will print legal-sized documents without having to e-mail them to myself first?

Comment: And... your question is?

Comment: Try to use Pages to print out the document. One can open Word documents in Pages. I'm thinking that this all is a bug in Word.

Comment: What printer and driver are you using when printing out the document?